# Validating a negative binomial glmm (using glmmadmb) in R

Tags: r, parameters, lme4

In this post, I am seeking help to figure out how I can make sure the negative binomial glmm I'm running meets its model assumptions.

I am working with a dataset that I collected in the field documenting the presence of recreational trails along 28 streams, that were surrounded by four different land use type, and found in and around 7 different protected areas (i.e. National Parks).  My original intention was to used a linear mixed model to assess the relationship between the "Recreational Trail Score" documented at each site and the different land use types, while accounting for the random effect of Park. Because the data has numerous (true) 0s, it was not possible to transform the data to attain a normal distribution. Consequently, I tried using a quasi-poisson glmm. This model was overdisperssed, so I decided to try using a negative bionomial model and am now seeking help to figure out if this model meets its assumptions or not.  (I am suspicious that there is a a problem with the model because results don't seem in line with what I would expect given the data distribution). 
Although I was able to locate [a post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/diagnostics-for-generalized-linear-mixed-models-specifically-residuals) that talks about validating glmms, its still unclear to me what exactly I need to check and how exactly I should check this to make sure the model is OK.

Below is R code that will allow you to reproduce the model I created. If anyone could provide feedback on:
a) if this model is meeting its assumptions, and how exactly you are able to confirm that 
b) if its not, what would you recommend doing as a next step?

```
#Create dataframe
RecreationalTrails<-c(5, 0, 0, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,4, 6, 8, 0, 0, 7)
LandUse<-c("Protected", "Agricultural", "Forestry", "Unprotected Forest", "Protected", "Agricultural", "Forestry", "Unprotected Forest",
       "Protected", "Agricultural", "Forestry", "Unprotected Forest","Protected", "Agricultural", "Forestry", "Unprotected Forest",
       "Protected", "Agricultural", "Forestry", "Unprotected Forest","Protected", "Agricultural", "Forestry", "Unprotected Forest",
       "Protected", "Agricultural", "Forestry", "Unprotected Forest")
Parc<-c("Monts Valin", "Monts Valin", "Monts Valin", "Monts Valin", "Fjords du Saguenay", "Fjords du Saguenay","Fjords du Saguenay",
    "Fjords du Saguenay", "Hautes Gorges", "Hautes Gorges","Hautes Gorges","Hautes Gorges", "Grands Jardins", "Grands Jardins",
    "Grands Jardins", "Grands Jardins", "Mont Tremblant", "Mont Tremblant", "Mont Tremblant", "Mont Tremblant", "Mauricie",
    "Mauricie", "Mauricie", "Mauricie", "Jacques Cartier", "Jacques Cartier", "Jacques Cartier", "Jacques Cartier")
ESCombinedDataRE<-data.frame(c("LandUse", "Parc", "RecreationalTrails"))
ESCombinedDataRE <- data.frame(LandUse, Parc, RecreationalTrails)
names(ESCombinedDataRE) <- c("LandUse", "Parc", "RecreationalTrails")
ESCombinedDataRE

#Visualize the data
RecTrails_boxplot<-ggplot(ESCombinedDataRE, aes(x=LandUse, y= 
RecreationalTrails, fill = LandUse))+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#0072B2", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442"))+
geom_boxplot()+
theme_gray(base_size = 14)+
theme(legend.position="none",axis.text.x=element_text(size=18,angle=25, 
hjust=1, vjust=1), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),axis.text.y = 
element_text(size = 13),axis.title.x = element_text(size = 18))+
labs(x="",y="Recreational Trails\nScore") 
RecTrails_boxplot

 #Run glmer negative binomial model
 install.packages("glmmADMB", 
             repos=c("http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/repos",
                     getOption("repos")),
             type="source")
 library(glmmADMB)

 R_glmer <- glmmadmb(RecreationalTrails ~ LandUse+ (1|Parc), 
 data=ESCombinedDataRE, family= "nbinom")

#Validate model
#Check overdispersion using this source code 
https://rdrr.io/github/markushuff/PsychHelperFunctions/src/R/overdisp_fun.R
overdisp_fun(R_glmer)

#How else should I be checking that this model is meeting its assumptions? 

#Model output and results 
summary(R_glmer)
summary(glht(R_glmer, linfct = mcp(LandUse = "Tukey")))

 #Use [this code][2] to look at conditional and marginal R2 values
```

http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/royinterface/suppl/2017/09/11/rsif.2017.0213.DC1/rsif20170213supp2.pdf

Comment: Modeling assumptions and validation are more statistical questions rather than specific programming questions. You are more likely to get better help with such questions at a site like [stats.se] where statistical questions are on-topic. They would probably be less interested in the code than the output produced so share that.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I now agree that this would be better to post on Cross Exchange and have created a new post here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344005/validating-a-negative-binomial-glmm-using-glmmadmb-in-r